# How to use OAuth with Github in a Safari extension

Tags: javascript, github, oauth, safari, safari-extension

I'm new to browser extensions. i'm trying to create a Safari extension that allows me to perform basic tasks in my Github account (Create a repo, for example). I'm doing it mostly to learn how to develop extensions while practicing my JS.

The issue is that in order to connect to Github I want to use OAuth, but I have no clue of how to do that. I have googled to see if I can find a library that I can use without any results. The main problem is that when trying to register my "application" with Github, I have no idea of what URL to provide for the main application and the callback, since it is not a web application what I'm developing; it's an extension.

Does anyone have any experience with this and can give me a tip on how to proceed? What URL should I use to register with Github? Is it possible to use OAuth from an extension at all? Is there a library, SDK, anything that can help do this job?
If this question can be broaden to any browser, just tell me and I will change the title to help others in the same situation.

Thanks to all for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used OAuth in a Safari extension and you're welcome to look at my code for an example (see link below), but this [JS library for Github](https://github.com/michael/github) might have all you need. I haven't used it, but it looks nice, and it supports "personal access tokens", which I take to be a kind of OAuth token for Github that doesn't require specifying a redirect URI.

My Safari extension [(Github link)](https://github.com/canisbos/Pickpocket) uses OAuth 2.0 to talk to the [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/) API. It doesn't use a library. For the redirect URI, I use the same URL as that of the page that initiates the whole authorization process, but with "?status=done" appended to it. The page's script checks its URL, and if the URL ends in that string, then it knows that the page was loaded by the authorization window and so it can proceed with getting the access token.

One thing you should be mindful of when using OAuth in any kind of client-side application, such as a browser extension, is that your OAuth app token will be exposed to the users of your app. Even if you encrypt it in the app or retrieve it from a server over https, a user can use the browser's built-in JS debugger to get the token, because you have to decrypt it at some point in order to use it. If someone steals your token, they can use to trick people into authorizing their nefarious app that pretends to be yours. It's up to you to decide whether this risk is tolerable. The only way to avoid this risk is to have your own server-side app that communicates with the third-party API, and your extension communicates with that. But then someone could learn from your extension's code how to talk to your server-side app, so I'm not sure whether that really buys you anything.

Comment: I'll take a look at your solution. The security concerns you mention are very relevant, and finding a workaround, if there is any, will help make robust extensions. I could instruct the user of the extension to create and provide a personal token. In such a case, where can I store it securely? Web local storage? The extensions settings?

Comment: I took a look at your solution. It looks very elegant. If you don't mind I'll model mine after yours regarding OAuth just to learn.

Comment: Safari does provide a secure storage space for settings in `safari.extension.secureSettings`, so you could use that for storing a user-provided token.

Comment: Great @canisbos, your code looks a bit complicated for me because I'm not all that experienced with JS, but I'll figure it out. I would appreciate if you could clarify something though: are there some elements that you defined in the Extension Builder that you don't use? I see various menus and at least two toolbar items, but I can't see where do you use some of them (I installed your extension). Thanks for your time and patience. That's all I need to head in the right direction.

Comment: @reydelleon Both toolbar items are used, but the "Put" one is not present by default; you have to add it to the toolbar using Safari's Customize Toolbar feature. The menu will only show up if you set the setting "When I click the toolbar button" to "Show a menu of possible actions" in the settings dialog. Some of the popovers defined in the Extension Builder are not used.